# Libgdx determinate camera can see object

Tags: libgdx

How is it possible? I want some method that determine that my 3d object can see my camera. So basically it is in the camera 2d viewport.

Comment: Do you want to determine if the camera can see the object or the opposite ? Your title & post are contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a libgdx `camera` has a `frustum`. So this should help you:

```
Frustum camFrustum = camera.frusum;
if (camFrustum. pointInFrustum(object.x, object.y, object.z)
   || camFrustum.pointInFrustum(object.x + object.width, object.y, object.z)
   || camFrustum.pointInFrustum(object.x + object.width, object.y + object. heigth, object.z)
   || camFrustum.pointInFrustum(object.x, object.y + object.height, object.z))
{
     // Object is in viewport
}
```

In 2D the object.z should be set to 1 or something like that i think. Just try it. For 3D there are also other methods: `sphereInFrustum`, `boundsInFrustum` and maybe others.
This methods are used for `Viewfrustum Culling`, which means, that object, which you do not see don't get rendered and the GPU has less things to do.

Comment: Good that i could help. Just for curiosity: Do you need this for culling (performance improvement) or for something else?

Comment: I just needed for a basic lensflare

Comment: Ah okay. Sounds interesting xD